# Auto add 2 time after click add

Tags: android, sqlite, bundle

I try to make a simple note. 
after I click save in add new note, they save as 2 note same content. it's mean they save 2 times. I don't know why.

create note in noteadapter class:

```
    public long createNote(String title, String body, String date) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Call create note in notelist class:

```
    private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
```

and event in noteedit class to add edit or del note:

```
    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

}

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_about:
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            if(note != null){
                note.close();
                note = null;
            }
            if(mRowId != null){
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(mRowId);
            }
            finish();

            return true;
        case R.id.menu_save:
            saveState();
            finish();           
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

        if(mRowId == null){
            mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, curDate);
        }else{
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body, curDate);
        }
    }


    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
            curText = note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY));
        }
    }
```

maybe problem here, when I try to get rowID:

```
mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }
```

my full code here:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/w1kyy7spc522za9/Notepad.zip

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Next time though, please paste just your relevent sources into something like http://pastebin.com/ :)

Comment: thank you, but i think my code is long and hard to show, so i post a like for everyone easy to download an read

Comment: @KevinHuynh you only have to post java code not the  project itself

Comment: paste useable code here rather than pasting link

Comment: done, anyone can help me, i try many way but no result :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `onOptionsItemSelected()` you're calling `saveState()` to save the note and then `finish()` the activity. (You probably should `return true;` after that to stop further processing the options item selection but that's not the problem here.) When the activity is finishing, it goes to paused state. In your `onPause()` you call `saveState()` again. Your `saveState()` updates an entry when `mRowId` is defined but you only set it in `onCreate()`, thus creating a new row in the database.

The solution is to capture the inserted row id and store it when doing the first insert, making the later calls to `saveState()` update the row. Your db helper `createNote()` already returns the row id you are not storing.